# Viewing the return value of a method in the watch window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

2 parts really;

```
// C# code
bool IsTrue()
{
  return true;
} // HERE
```

1. Is the return value from the above method stored in the AX register when the instruction pointer is *HERE*
2. Simply for convenience how can I get that register in the watch window (in addition to the register window), I tried AX, $AX, &AX, {AX} and used EAX or RAX with these tokens to no avail

EDIT: An objective is that I don't have to alter the code to see the results so adding a temp variable is out, the method above is a **vast** simplification and in the real code, as is common, these kinds of calls are nested, or in lambda expressions or multi element logical expressions

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164996/how-do-i-discover-the-return-value-at-the-end-of-a-function-when-debugging-in-vs2

Comment: Or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/06/10/how-to-view-the-return-value-of-a-c-or-vb-method-in-the-vs-debugger.aspx

Comment: That's awkward. I was so sure there's a CPU Registers window in the Debugging menu but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: there is a registers window (look off the Debug - Windows menu item), I can look at values in there but it'd be nice if I can just look at the register I want and maybe even cast it to something pretty :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this feature will be available in VS2013 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: I wrote a commercial tool for Visual Studio called OzCode (formerly known as 'BugAid') that allows you to do this even in VS2012 and VS2010. It allows you to see not only the value that is going to be returned from a method, but also the values returned from any method calls you just stepped over. This feature is called 'Simplify', see http://www.oz-code.com/

Comment: $ReturnValue (if you don't want to open the above link)  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I want to know the return value of a function, I assign the value to a variable and return that variable instead. Old habits of Console.WriteLine()-debugging.. but it works.